# Можно ли использовать миграции EF CodeFirst для Azure SQL Server?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, teamcity

Возник такой вопрос - имеем ВМ, развернутую на Azure. В проекте имеются миграции Code First. Код попадает на ВМ из GitLab с помощью TeamCity. Будут ли они действовать для Azure SQL Server? Как это сделать? Шагом в TeamCity или какие-то еще варианты есть?